# Cybersource Refunds REST API

Tags: payment-gateway, cybersource

In my case: I process the payment and payment went success but somehow my internal API fails where I store the payment details or ledger kind of. Now I want to refund back to customer.
So I found out this endpoint "pts/v2/payments/{id}/refunds", where I pass the paymentId in the query param and order info in the body. But the response is

```
{"submitTimeUtc":"2020-08-18T07:26:18Z","status":"INVALID_REQUEST","reason":"INVALID_DATA","message":"Declined - One or more fields in the request contains invalid data"}
```

I tried from here too https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_refund
the same thing.

I also check out the sample java code https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-rest-samples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/samples/Payments/Refund/RefundPayment.java

it does the weird things it first creates payment and then refunds it. Please help me out how the flow and whats need to do for this API.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are using and I don't see your code, but I ran into the same issue myself. Instead of using the `SimpleAuthorizationInternet()` function to retrieve details of the payment, I just pass in the ID as I need.

So, instead of:

```
SimpleAuthorizationInternet.userCapture = true;
PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response paymentResponse = SimpleAuthorizationInternet.run();
String id = paymentResponse.getId();
```

... don't call the function and remove the lines:

```
SimpleAuthorizationInternet.userCapture = true;
PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response paymentResponse = SimpleAuthorizationInternet.run();
```

.. if you have the payment ID, just use it straight in the function:

```
String id = '123456789321654987'
```

Better still, pass it into the function call and use that var instead of the hard-coded string above.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using Java for this integration, I use keypair authorization not Simple authorization. 
This issue was resolved as I was not passing some fields with request. Sorry I forgot to close this issue

Comment: @Aakash Thomas  I'm getting the same error. can you please post the solution?